# Spring websockets not registering user when Connecting from Postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-websocket

I have following configuration for websockets

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class SocketBrokerConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler());
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler()).withSockJS();
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {

    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(final ServerHttpRequest request,
            final WebSocketHandler wsHandler, final Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        final String userId = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest().getParameter("userId");
        return new UserPrincipal(userId);
    }
}
```

I have created this end point to test web sockets

```
   @GetMapping("/triggerMessage")
    public String trigger(){
        template.convertAndSendToUser("1","/topic/greetings",new Greeting("Testing"));
        return "Success";
    }
```

I am using Postman to connect to web socket url. I am able to connect (Ignore disconnect message. I disconnected manually.). But when I try to publish message I don't see anything on postman console.

[image: Post man screenshot]

After debugging further I found the user is not been added to the DefaultSimpUserRegistry class. This class contains  a method which adds and removes the user from registry.

```
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
```

The user which I used to connect to was endpoint  is not added to registry.

This method is not getting called during connect event but when I click on disconnect on Postman this method gets called.

Any help is appreciated .